# webkitPersistentStorage and webkitTemporaryStorage no longer available in WebWorker navigator?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker, fileapi

My Chrome Browser just updated it self from v39 to v40 (40.0.2214.91 m) and my application I'm developing just stopped working.

It seems they removed `webkitPersistentStorage` from the `Worker navigator` object. It is still there in the `main navigator` object.

The data type of the object was `DeprecatedStorageQuota` in the `Worker navigator` and still is so in the `main navigator`.

Can anyone tell me how to access this object the correct way? I guess they removed it because it was deprecated, but why only from workers and not the main thread? And where has this functionality gone now?

I need it to download files in the background (in a Web Worker) (this is not a normal web application used on the Internet, it's for an unmanned embedded systems appliance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just independently found this: https://crbug.com/604292. It was deleted by accident a long time ago (though my rough calculations put this deletion at at Chrome 39, not 40; see Comment 1) and not many people noticed apparently.

Unfortunately, because it is deprecated, we made the decision to not put it back in, so this will not be fixed. Instead, the standardized `WorkerNavigator.storage` will be available (but that is currently experimental only).

Comment: Thanks for the information!
It was quite a long time ago now but I recall that I was doing active development and then during lunch I updated the browser to get the newest and latest, and then everything stoppen working.
I have since the abandoned using web workers partly because the embedded browser environment that some manufacturers were using on their devices didn't support web workers.